# 1991 suburban 350 TBI no start

Tags: chevrolet, cranks-wont-run, suburban, spark

If in fact I do get a spark though it orange in color does that prove that the ignition control module is good? A little background here, she was running in park idling strong and stop running cold dead. Not a fart not a hiccup not a wine not a wheeze nothing just dead! I’m questioning the control module At $40 a pop they’re getting expensive. No one test them anymore, if you know how please advise.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the ICM, but I'm thinking it would be that or the coil. I'm thinking if it was the ICM you'd not be getting any spark at all, while a weak spark (it should be bluish-white if healthy) might be pointing to a coil. Those you can check pretty easily.

Comment: What OBD codes are you getting?

Comment: I hate to admit it but doing the gauges in the dash I lost the wire to the check engine light I am searching for as I’m doing all these other things at the same time. Once I locate check engine light wire I will reinstall.  I realized the moment she died I missed something. What a nightmare! Isnt hindsight a great thing!?! By chance anyone know what color it is? Ha!

Comment: Did you check the fuel pump?

Comment: Well she cranks she fires but she won’t run until I get that dashboard back together. It is with great enthusiasm I believe I see the light at the end of this dark dark tunnel. So I replace the coil I replaced, the distributor ignition control module, Went ahead rebuilt top half of the throttlebody, cap and rotor of course and I believe my brand new diehard has diedeasy. I believe she may have a dead cell in it. She just waiting to drain just for the mild amount of cranking that I’m doing but will investigate that.